# How to feed 2-state voltage into PC?

Tags: pcb-design, rs232, serial-bus

I have a simple circuit that generates +5V under normal conditions but goes down to 0 when something is wrong. I need to feed this voltage into a PC (running Ubuntu) and write a program to monitor the system.

At first, I thought I simply need to connect the wire to pin 2 (RX) and start polling the serial port in my program. For each byte that I read, if I get a value 0xFF, it would indicate normal operations.

After doing some more reading, I am a bit confused. It seems the serial port requires a handshake signal as well. Plus, it is a looking for a start and end marker. Moreover, the serial port seems to require -3V to -12V for logical 1. My input is +5V.

I am wondering if there is an easier and inexpensive solution to feed 2-state voltage into PC. Serial port seems to be an obvious choice but there may be a better option.

FYI, the current sensor circuit that I have is on a breadboard but am considering putting it on a PCB and use a PCI slot as a holder for the PCB.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 3):

In this day and age, USB is probably the interface you want to use.

So, you're looking for something that does USB<->GPIO.

A lot of FTDI eval boards do that, and clones do that, too.

In principle, you can use your serial port idea with any USB<->TTL adapter (if you add a voltage divider to bring down your 5 V to 3.3V), if that adapter has a handshake-free mode.

Personally, the easiest way of doing this is, for me, probably getting one of the many, many ARM microcontroller tinker / eval boards. The Arduino platform is popular, but a Teensy or any ST Nucleo / Cypress Eval … board should do, too. Downside is: you'll end up writing Firmware. That's something that you'd have to get used to first, but it'd undoubtedly have many advantages if your problem involves executing some kind of logic on a hardware level.

Oh, and very oldschool: Use your control voltage to switch on or off any audible tone generator, and feed that into your sound card.

Comment: To add to the FTDI suggestion, if OP doesn't want to develop any firmware, something like Adafruit's FT232H board would work well, as it has a Python library and should work OOTB.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will first look at using DSR as my input. If this doesn't work, I can look at the suggested boards.

Answer (score 1):

If your PC has serial ports, then you can use the status bits CTS and DSR as digital inputs.
When you tried to use the Rx port, the operating system would filter this out (you don't get a string of 'FF's) as a Break signal.

While the RS232 lines accept +9/-9, the vast majority of RS232 receivers will work well with just TTL level signaling. So your 0-5 V signal should work.
You can use the internal RS232 ports on your computer or you could plug in a USB/RS232 cable.
There is ready support for reading CTS/DSR and writing DTR/RTS pins on the interface in [PySerial](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.cts) library.